# Can SharePoint Designer 2007 be used with SharePoint 2010 Workflows?

Tags: migration, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to use SharePoint Designer 2007 to edit workflows in SharePoint 2010?  I am working in an environment where users are restricted from downloading SharePoint Designer 2010, but we are migrating from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.  There are several workflows in SharePoint 2007 that were developed using SharePoint Designer 2007.  Are there any creative ways to migrate the 2007 workflows over to SharePoint 2010 that would still allow users to edit these workflows with SharePoint Designer 2007?  (and yes, I realize that SharePoint Designer 2010 is a free download, but our environment has not approved this program yet).

Answer (score 1):

No you wont be able to open a 2007 site using SharePoint 2010 which bring me to think you cant edit a SP 2007 workflow using SPD 2010